# How to check the number of keys have a certain value in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

What I am trying to figure out is how do you check if a hashmap (which in my case could have any number of keys) has only one of a certain value assigned to it.  I'm struggling to explain this here.

If I have a hashmap with 10 keys (each is players in a game assigned to have a gamestate depending on what "gamestate" they are in) and there is only one player with the game state IN_GAME, then how do I check that there is in fact only one Key assigned with the value IN_GAME, and there isn't two keys with that value?

Comment: Have you considered a [`Guava BiMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)?

Comment: @JoeC I am kinda a noob still so I will look that up. Thanks.

Comment: One way of avoiding the problem is to have a variable called `playerInGame`. Then it can hold only one player (or zero with `null`).

Comment: So i dont think BiMap would work here because there can be multiple players mapped to same state ie `NOT_IN_GAME`. The single variable @ChaiT.Rex solution seems the most simple to me. It would make it very easy to access the in game player as well as enforce there is only one player in game at a time.

Comment: Do you want to check only for one specific value, or are you not expecting any duplicates at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use streams for that:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
// adding data
long count = data.values().stream().filter(v -> v.equals("IN_GAME")).count();
```

Count will return the number of "IN_GAME" values in your map.

Comment: I am already doing this.  But how do I check if only one player has this value assigned to them?

Comment: @Chai T. Rex, tnx for the comment. I've modified my answer

Comment: Or `filter("IN_GAME"::equals)`, or `Predicate.isEqual("IN_GAME")`

Answer (score 0):

Using an Iterator instance seems like solve the problem.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Stack{

public static void main(String[] args){
    //create a hashmap
    HashMap<Integer, String> map =  new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    //populate with dummy out-game entries
    for(int i = 0; i < 8;i++){
        map.put(i, "OUT-GAME");
    }

    // add the last two with in-game value
    map.put(8, "IN-GAME");
    map.put(9, "IN-GAME");

    //declare an iterator on map
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

    //number of time "in-game" is encountered
    int check = 0;

    //while the iterator has  more to go
    while(it.hasNext()){

        //get the key-value pairs and print them just for checking 
        //the entries

        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry<Integer,String>) it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " +  pair.getValue());

        //if the value "in-game" is encountered increment the check by 1

        if(pair.getValue().equals("IN-GAME")){
            System.out.println("We have a player in game");
            check++;
        }

        //if "in-game" is encountered more than once, then print an alarm

        if(check > 1){
            System.out.println("More than 1 player in game. There's something wrong");
        }
    }

    //if there's only one player with "in-game", inform me

    if(check == 1){
        System.out.println("We have exactly one player in the game");
    }
}
}
```

The above code informs you, there are more than one player with "in-game" property on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there are *any* duplicates values, the simplest solution is to dump it in a set and compare the result size to the original:

```
boolean hasDuplicates = new HashSet<>(map.values()).size() < map.size();
```